# Implementing a clickable image for delete action in CakePHP?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, cakephp-1.3

I would like to make use of a click-able image to fire a delete action. When clicked I also need to load an alert message to confirm the operation. Can anyone suggest how to implement it into my existing code as follows:

```
echo $popup->link($html->image("delete.jpg", array('alt' => 'Delete', 'title'=>'Delete Enquiry')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I cake php we are giving alert like this:-

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete', true), array('action' => 'delete', $tduPrice['TduPrice']['id']), null, sprintf(__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', true), $tduPrice['TduPrice']['id'])); ?>
```

modify it according to your code..